# BPF SDK path does not exist

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I'm following the Anchor docs [here](https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/getting-started/installation.html), but I keep getting this error...

`BPF SDK path does not exist: /Users/herbie/.cargo/bin/sdk/bpf: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

I ran `ls -al /Users/herbie/.cargo/bin` and got this output:

```
total 239152
drwxr-xr-x  17 herbie  staff       544 31 Jan 16:55 .
drwxr-xr-x   9 herbie  staff       288 13 Dec 11:58 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 herbie  staff  12574724 31 Jan 16:49 anchor
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 cargo
-rwxr-xr-x   1 herbie  staff   7578989 14 Dec 14:05 cargo-build-bpf
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 cargo-clippy
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 cargo-fmt
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 cargo-miri
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 clippy-driver
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rls
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rust-gdb
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rust-lldb
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rustc
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rustdoc
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rustfmt
-rwxr-xr-x  12 herbie  staff   8521112 31 Jan 16:55 rustup
```

Haven't found much online, and have never heard of BPF before...

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear when you're getting the error during the installation, but here's a few things to try:

- be sure that you're using an up-to-date version of Rust stable with `rustup update stable`
- check that you're using the Solana CLI version designated in the docs using `solana -V`
- run `cargo build-bpf` on the hello world Rust application: https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/tree/master/src/program-rust

For more reference, BPF is the bytecode format used by on-chain programs with Solana.  You can find some more info at the links contained within https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview#berkeley-packet-filter-bpf

Comment: No luck unfortunately... `➜  test1 anchor build
BPF SDK path does not exist: /Users/herbie/.cargo/bin/sdk/bpf: No such file or directory (os error 2)
➜  test1 solana -V
solana-cli 1.9.1 (src:b66e2ae3; feat:4100269022)
➜  test1 cargo build-bpf
BPF SDK path does not exist: /Users/herbie/.cargo/bin/sdk/bpf: No such file or directory (os error 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the solana cache before running your code. It worked for me. Basically, the BPF SDK hasn't been installed accurately.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/solana/*
```

After deleting the solana cache run. It should download the BPF SDK again

```
solana build
```